# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

роли выдаёт, а когда убираешь реакцию с сообщения, выдаёт ошибку "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'", нигде не могу найти, как пофиксить
Код:

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client()

from discord import user
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == 1003651093206663210 and payload.emoji.name == "✅":
            guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, id=payload.guild_id)
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='╬ㅤㅤㅤヾ(≧▽≦*)oㅤㅤㅤ╬')
            await payload.member.add_roles(role)
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 938726443842682892 and payload.emoji.name =="✅":
            guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, id=payload.guild_id)
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='╬ㅤㅤㅤヾ(≧▽≦*)oㅤㅤㅤ╬')
            await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
```

**UPD** Пофиксил добавив:
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не понимаю в ботах, но ошибка дает представление, что этого можно избежать, добавив проверку для `payload.member`

```py
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='╬ㅤㅤㅤヾ(≧▽≦*)oㅤㅤㅤ╬')
if payload.member:
    await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
```

**UPD**

По конкретнее решение вопроса можно найти здесь [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68412422/10562663), автор ответа [Dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14449816/dominik)

Код с включенными отладочными `print`'ами

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    print("Guild checked.")
    member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
    print("Member checked.")
    if payload.message_id == 865402961585111111:
        print("Got message.")
        if str(payload.emoji) == "✅":
            print("Checked for the reaction.")
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Announcements')
            print("Got the role.")
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)

        if role is not None:
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print("Removed the role")
```

Comment: ошибки больше нет, но действие "await payload.member.remove_roles(role)" бот так и не выполняет

Comment: @Artyom следовательно, надо разобраться почему `payload.member` возвращает None